# How can I simplify this function - return key value from array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have written the following function which returns the value of a key which is the account prefix of a cPanel account.
[prefix] = 'oneclick_'

The function works but I'm only a beginner and I'm sure there's an easier and better way to write this function.

```
<?php
// Get data from cPanel API
$array = $cp_db_restrictions['cpanelresult']['result']['data'];

//Pass array of $data to function
db_prefix( $array );

//Function accepts array of $data
function db_prefix( $array ) {
  if( count( $array ) > 0 ) {
      return $array['prefix'];
  } else {
      return "No prefix";
  }
}
?>

<?php echo db_prefix($array); ?>
```

The function echos "oneclick_"

**EDIT:**
This is the code which returns the array:

```
$cp_db_restrictions = $cpanel->uapi(
      'Mysql', 'get_restrictions'
  );
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to add that into the function. When I try I get the following error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: array in ...

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function uapi() on null in...

**SOLUTION***

So, thanks to Nick's answer here is the solution. You must make sure to declare the cPanel class at the top of the document and within the same PHP tags.

```
<?php
include("/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php"); // Instantiate the CPANEL object.
$cpanel = new CPANEL();

function db_prefix($cpanel) {
      $cp_db_restrictions = $cpanel->uapi('Mysql', 'get_restrictions');
      $array = $cp_db_restrictions['cpanelresult']['result']['data'];
      return $array['prefix'] ?? 'No prefix';
} ?>
<?php echo db_prefix($cpanel); ?>
```

Comment: perhaps use `$array['prefix'] ?? 'No prefix'` to retrieve the value if it exists, or return a default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP7 you can just use the null coalescing operator [`??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
echo $array['prefix'] ?? 'No prefix';
```

Comment: is there a way to place the array within the function instead of passing it through an argument?

Comment: @HansDesjarlais you could declare it as a global variable (`global $array`) inside the function, but it is generally considered better practice to pass variables as arguments. Your other alternative might be to include the code which generates the `$cp_db_restrictions` array inside your function so that it did not need the argument.

Comment: that's what I'm having an issue with. Either I'm doing it wrong or the cPanel API call can't be called within a function. Which I think don't makes sense... I edited my question.

Comment: @HansDesjarlais yeah, unfortunately you will still run into issues with having to pass variables into the function (in this case it would be `$cpanel` - although that would be a more reasonable variable to use as a global) but it might be cleaner e.g. https://3v4l.org/P9jmb

Comment: your bit of code did it. See the edit with the solution.